# Paralelize multiple calls of asynchronous function

Tags: python, asynchronous, concurrency, multiprocessing, python-asyncio

I have the following scenario:

```
from time import sleep

async def do_a(a):
    sleep(0.001)
    return 1*a

async def do_b(a):
    sleep(0.01)
    return 2*a

async def do_c(b):
    sleep(1)
    return 3*b


async def my_func():
    results = []
    for i in range(3):
        a = await do_a(i)
        b = await do_b(a)
        c = await do_c(b)
        results.append(c)
    return results

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import asyncio
    print(asyncio.run(my_func()))
```

Basically, I am calling asynchronous functions in a loop. Executing the above code shows it run in ~3s. I would like to call each procedure in parallel, so the expected time would drop to ~1s (I know this overhead is a little bit too optimistic, but to optimize the running time at least a bit). I have been looking into different python libraries that I think could help, but having trouble deciding which one is useful in this case. Python's multiprocessing, threading and concurrent.futures all seem to implement one form or another of parallelism/concurrency. 
What should I do? Can you show me how you would proceed in this case?

Comment: oh, I intended to provide a small example. I put sleep calls in the places I do "heavy" work (querying a database in do_a, reading from disk in do_b, matrix multiplicacion in do_c ..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`asyncio.sleep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#sleeping) instead of [`time.sleep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep). If you want everything to run concurrently, this is one way you can do it with [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently):

```py
import asyncio

async def do_a(a):
    await asyncio.sleep(0.001)
    return 1*a

async def do_b(a):
    await asyncio.sleep(0.01)
    return 2*a

async def do_c(b):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return 3*b

async def do_abc(i):
    a = await do_a(i)
    b = await do_b(a)
    return await do_c(b)

async def my_func():
    return await asyncio.gather(*map(do_abc, range(3)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import asyncio
    print(asyncio.run(my_func()))
    # [0, 6, 12]
```

If the actual code that runs instead of `sleep` is synchronous (blocking), you would do essentially the same, only you would have to defer that work to an [executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#executing-code-in-thread-or-process-pools).

Comment: Thank you very much! I still have to dig deeper into executor, but it seems it's not my case.